# Find maximum element in an RDD in Pyspark by using map/filter

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

```
a = sc.parallelize((1,9,3,10))
```

I want to find the maximum element in a without using any max function.

I tried
    a.filter( lambda x,y: x if x>y else y)

I am not able to compare elements in the RDD. How do I use for loop or if else condition properly in the map/filter function. Is it possible?

Thank you.

I was trying to post a different question. But not able to.

```
a = sc.parallelize((11,7,20,10,1,7))
```

I want to sort the elements in increasing order without using sort() function.

I tried:

```
def srt(a,b):
if a>b:
    i=a
    a=b
    b=i   

final=a.map(lambda x,y: srt(x,y))
```

I am not getting the required result.

I want to get

```
  (1,7,7,10,11,20)
```

thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot find the max/min using filters. You may achieve that using comparison in a reduce operation:

```
a = sc.parallelize([1,9,3,10])
max_val = a.reduce(lambda a, b: a if a > b else b)
```

The lambda just compares and returns the bigger of 2 values.

Comment: Thank you.

I just have one more query. Is is possible to incorporate a for loop in the reduce/map/filter function

Comment: You can declare a function `func` that does whatever you want, and you can have any kind of control flow in it. Then you can replace the lambda expression above with the function name. In the case of this reduce, your function will have to take 2 parameters (just as the lambda does).

Comment: Thank you. If you don't mind, I have one more query. I have updated the question. I was trying to sort the elements in an RDD without using the sort() function. But its not working. Thank you.

Comment: Would you please post that on a different question? That would help with search results.

Comment: Okay. Sorry. I will do that. Its just I have to wait for 90 minutes to post the next question. Thanks.